# iPhone - NSUserDefaults perimeter

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults

When setting values in NSUSerDefaults, may other apps that would know my used keys will be able to read my values ? I ask this because I can see that some values that are not mine are accessible, like `NSArray* languages = [defaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];`that I would had expected to find elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just check it on my device - no, user defaults stored in one app are inaccessable from another app.
But as you said exist some system-defined values, that shared by system to all apps.

p.s. Otherwise it will conflict with one of the basic iOS paradigm - sandbox. One separate sandbox for every app.